# How do I create multibranch lines in Gliffy?

Tags: gliffy

I have a need to create "multibranch" lines. I am doing it now by overlaying several single lines from the start point to various endpoints  (or from various startpoints to the same endpoint)

This works OK if the line style is solid, but for dashed lines the dashes do not always line up.

For example consider this diagram snippet... The long dash lines all come from the project but point to various green circles. The leftmost two look OK but by the time you get to the right most, the dashes line up in a way that makes the line look solid.

Similarly for the dotted lines on the bottom, they come from various green circles but go to the right and up. Overlappping of the lines causes a solid section underneath the V2.1 tag.

"commit" diagram with example dashed and dotted lines that do not render correctly:

[image]

I can create these in Visio and Visio keeps the styles correct, but is this doable in Gliffy? (I can't easily use Visio in this instance, we embed our Gliffy diagrams in Confluence)

Basically, what I do now in Gliffy is start multiple copies of the same line and overlay them to get the "branching" effect. I want the "Visio smart connector" behaviour, but it may not be possible. If I know it is not, I will use a different way of showing line differences.

Comment: Please add screenshot to the question!

Comment: The question has an imgur link, not sure how to get it to render directly if it's not rendering for you. Did you try clicking the link?